# ST_Intersection with only one polygon type

Tags: postgis, sql

I am using this sql-query to execute an intersection:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection (schablone.geom, eingangsdaten.geom)) --as geom2
     FROM schablone, eingangsdaten
     JOIN schablone b
     ON ST_Intersects (eingangsdaten.geom, b.geom)
     WHERE schablone.id = 4);
```

The result are different geometry types (polygon, multipolygon...). I need the result geometries with one geometry type. Is this possible?

Comment: It is not clear what is the purpose of your query. Can you describe it?

Comment: You probably want ST_CollectionExtract to limit to certain types. However, you need to state what you are expecting the output to be. You say you want one geometry type -- which one?

Comment: I will create a new table which contains  the result of this query. The query works fine.  But for this project I have to import this table to qgis.  And the Problem is qgis has some restrictions. The layer muss have only one geometry typ inside the geometry column ( for example only multipolygons) .  This is my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`ST_Multi()`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Multi.html) to convert all geometries to multigeometries:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_MULTI(ST_Intersection (schablone.geom, eingangsdaten.geom))) --as geom2
   FROM schablone, eingangsdaten
   JOIN schablone b
   ON ST_Intersects (eingangsdaten.geom, b.geom)
   WHERE schablone.id = 4);
```

This of course doesn't help if you have Polygons, Lines and Points mixed. Then you would need to use something like this: `ST_MULTI(ST_BUFFER(geom,0))`

For GeometryCollections you can use [`ST_CollectionExtract()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_CollectionExtract.html)

Comment: thanks it is working a little bit. Now I have instead of Polygons and Multipolygons only Multipolygons in the table. But in addition to that I have sometimes geometrycollections... At the end I will create a new table inside postgis and after the execution I wanna import the table into qgis. But therefore I have to use only one geometry typ for one layer. So at the moment I cannot import the layer into qgis...

Comment: I updated my answer to support Collections